# Calculate Weighted Cost (Avg) of a product in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Product table with it's Sale, Purchase, Begin and End stock for a given day. I have omitted date and other products in the below sample for simplicity. I am trying to get the Avg Cost of a product using T-SQL. I am puzzled with this problem since it relies on the previous record(day)'s AvgCost which is null to start with.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY, ProductId INT, 
    BeginInvt DECIMAL(9,2), SaleQty DECIMAL(9,2), SalePrice DECIMAL(5,3), 
    PurQty DECIMAL(9,2) NULL, PurCost DECIMAL(5,3) NULL, EndingInvt DECIMAL(9,2))

INSERT @tbl (ProductId, BeginInvt, SaleQty, SalePrice, PurQty, PurCost, EndingInvt )
VALUES 
(1,3000,500,2.000,NULL,NULL,2500),
(1,2500,250,2.000,2000,1.800,4250),
(1,4250,300,2.000,NULL,NULL,3950),
(1,3950,900,2.000,4000,1.850,7050),
(1,7050,300,2.000,NULL,NULL,6750),
(1,6750,300,2.000,NULL,NULL,6450),
(1,6450,300,2.000,5000,1.750,11150),
(1,11150,300,2.000,NULL,NULL,10850)
```

I want to get the AvgCost for the above rows. Given that initial stock of 3000 items' avg cost is 1.9. The solution should have the result like this

I am looking for output with the column AvgCost as below. This table can have different products. Once I have the solution I can apply window function to partition the calculations.

**Expected Result**

```
Id   ProductId   BeginInvt   SaleQty  SalePrice  PurQty    PurCost  EndingInvt  AvgCost
---- ----------- ----------- -------- ---------- --------- -------- ----------- --------
1    1           3000.00     500.00   2.000      NULL      NULL     2500.00     1.90000
2    1           2500.00     250.00   2.000      2000.00   1.800    4250.00     1.85556
3    1           4250.00     300.00   2.000      NULL      NULL     3950.00     1.85556
4    1           3950.00     900.00   2.000      4000.00   1.850    7050.00     1.85276
5    1           7050.00     300.00   2.000      NULL      NULL     6750.00     1.85276
6    1           6750.00     300.00   2.000      NULL      NULL     6450.00     1.85276
7    1           6450.00     300.00   2.000      5000.00   1.750    11150.00    1.80789
8    1           11150.00    300.00   2.000      NULL      NULL     10850.00    1.80789
```

AvgCost for a row can be calculated by doing the weighted avg of BeginInvt and Pur values as follows:

```
((BeginInvt*prevous_day_avgcost)+(PurQty*PurCost))/(BeginInvt+PurQty)
```

***prevous_day_avgcost*** is the problem for me with set based calculations

Thanks for the help...

Comment: how is the initial average cost calculated?

Comment: @vkp, I got that from initial purchase value of 3000 items or if there were earlier records then it can be previous day's AvgCost. This will be available to me when I start the calculations. Thanks

Comment: If you add a sequence number to your table you can do it with LAG() or a recursive CTE.  Right now there is not order in @tbl so it is impossible. oh wait... I see the id column -- you want that as the order?

Comment: Then how prevous_day_avgcost for first row? How first row avgcost is calculated as 1.9?

Comment: @Hogan, yes that defines the order. So you can use that for order. Thanks

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, You can declare that as variable with the value of 1.9 and use that to start off. Or you can keep the BeginInvt for first row as 0, and have PurQty = 3000 and PurCost = 1.9. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: @Hogan, I saw your answer using LAG and then it was removed, it is possible using LAG? Just curious. Thanks

Comment: I wrote something @Bharat but then when I tried it, it failed.  LAG works with the source table not with the result and you need to use the result in the next row -- so a variable or recursive CTE is needed.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Hogan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it using a recursive cte. This is because you wouldn't know the avgCost for each row until the previous calculation is complete. So you can do this iteratively.

```
with rownums as (select t.*,row_number() over(partition by productId order by id) as rnum from @tbl t)
,cte as (select rnum,id,ProductId, BeginInvt, SaleQty, SalePrice, 
         PurQty, PurCost, EndingInvt ,cast(1.9 as decimal(38,5)) as avgCost --replace this with a calculation if you know it.
         from rownums 
         where rnum=1
         union all
         select r2.rnum,r2.id,r2.ProductId, r2.BeginInvt, r2.SaleQty, r2.SalePrice, r2.PurQty, r2.PurCost, r2.EndingInvt, 
         cast(((r2.BeginInvt*r1.avgCost)+(coalesce(r2.PurQty,0)*coalesce(r2.PurCost,0)))/(r2.BeginInvt+coalesce(r2.PurQty,0)) as decimal(38,5))
         from cte r1
         join rownums r2 on r1.productId=r2.productId and r2.rnum=r1.rnum+1
        ) 
select ProductId, BeginInvt, SaleQty, SalePrice, PurQty, PurCost, EndingInvt, avgCost
from cte
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/WGS25360)

Comment: why use row_number() when he has ID?

Comment: to be safe in case there are missing id's.

Comment: @vkp, This is Great! I got the expected result. I need to understand the query in more detail. Also, how would this perform with 1000s of records? Thanks a lot...